# Read xml file and store the key value in hashtable using powershell

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I need to read below xml file and store it in hash table.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ConfigValues>
   <Dev>
     <item Key="dbconn" Value ="Data Source=xlvxdev.cumulus.com,1615;Initial Catalog=FPTR_XLVX;Security=true;"/>
   </Dev>
   <QA>
     <item Key="dbconn" Value ="Data Source=xlvxqa.cumulus.com,1615;Initial Catalog=OPSR_CVRC;Security=true;"/>
   </QA>
   <PP>
     <item Key="dbconn" Value ="Data Source=xlvxpreprd.cumulus.com,1615;Initial Catalog=OPSR_CVRC;Security=true;"/>
   </PP>
   <PROD>
     <item Key="dbconn" Value ="Data Source=xlvxprd.cumulus.com,1615;Initial Catalog=OPSR_CVRC;Security=true;"/>
   </PROD>
</ConfigValues>
```

I tried writing below powershell and able to get the attributes key value but I need to store it on the hashtable so that I can retrieve the value as needed.

```
$URLS = [xml](Get-Content 'C:\Desktop\Variables.xml')

$URLS.ConfigValues.Dev.item | where {$_.key -eq 'connCVRC'}
```

```
Key      Value
---      -----
connCVRC Data Source=xlvxdev.cumulus.com,1615;Initial Catalog=FPTR_XLVX;Security=true;
```

Comment: It's not quite clear what do you want as output, is it `$xml.ConfigValues.Dev.Item.Value.Split(';') | ConvertFrom-StringData`? Please add an expected result to your question.

Comment: Thanks for reach out to me. I was looking for the same results provided in below answer by mklement0

Answer (score 4):

```sh
# Parse the XML file into an XML DOM
($xml = [xml]::new()).Load((Convert-Path C:\Desktop\Variables.xml))

# Initialize the (ordered) output hashtable.
$hash = [ordered] @{}

# Populate the hashtable with the <ConfigValues> child element 
# names as the key, and their <item> child's Value attribute as the value.
$xml.ConfigValues.ChildNodes.ForEach({
   $hash[$_.Name] = $_.item.Value
})

$hash # output
```

The above yields:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
Dev                            Data Source=xlvxdev.cumulus.com,1615;Initial Catalog=FPTR_XLVX;Security=true;
QA                             Data Source=xlvxqa.cumulus.com,1615;Initial Catalog=OPSR_CVRC;Security=true;
PP                             Data Source=xlvxpreprd.cumulus.com,1615;Initial Catalog=OPSR_CVRC;Security=true;
PROD                           Data Source=xlvxprd.cumulus.com,1615;Initial Catalog=OPSR_CVRC;Security=true;
```

Comment: My pleasure, @pandeg87. It sounds like this answer solves your problem, but I'm not certain, based on your comment. Either way, please allow me to give you the standard advice to newcomers in the next comment: